# AngularJS show escaped HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello considering I get the following code from my HTML from my server:

```
&quote;<b>Demo</b>&quote; &amp;Hase&gt;
```

How could I render that as:

"Demo"

while demo will be "fat", is there a way in AngularJS? Actually getting demo to bold is no problem with `$sce` and `ng-bind-html` however the other stuff will still be "e; or & instead of their unescaped counterpart.

The HTML is coming from elasticsearch's highlighting function with `escape: 'html'` so actually we don't escape the data into elasticsearch and let elasticsearch do it.

This actually makes it work:

```
    function unescapeHtml(safe) {
        return safe.replace(/&amp;/g, '\&') // this needs to be /& ?!
            .replace(/&lt;/g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/&gt;/g, '&gt;')
            .replace(/&quot;/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/&apos;/g, '&apos;')
            .replace(/&#039;/g, "\'");
    }
```

not sure why tough... That's stupid, maybe somebody can enlighten me. maybe charset issues?!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - $sce.trustAsHtml('&quot;<b>Demo</b>&quot;') -> this would render "Demo" in bold

Comment: actually it does render &quot;Demo&quote;

Comment: How you are binding that value to view ? Can you please share that ?

Comment: either with {{ $ctrl.content }} or with <span ng-bind-html="$ctrl.content"></span> however doesn't make a difference. Actually the output comes from elasticsearch's highlighting function with `escape: "html"`

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve what you want by creating a custom filter and unescaping html

```
 angular.module('app', [])
     .filter('unescape', function($sce) {

          function unescapeHtml(safe) {
             return safe.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
                .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
                .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
                .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
                .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
          }

          return function(input) {
               var unescaped = unescapeHtml(input);
               return $sce.trustAsHtml(unescaped);
          };
     });
```

And use that this way

```
{{ $ctrl.content | unescape }}
```

Comment: this makes no sense, sorry but then I would have the issue with XSS.